# How to convert pyplot image in bytes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to convert an image produced with pyplot in bytes and write those bytes in a file to save my plot as an image on my computer.

**For outsiders reason i can't use `savefig` to save directly the plot on a file**

With all the informations taken online and from other questions i arrived at this point:

```
    plt.hist(arg)
    plt.show()
    bio = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(bio, format="png")

#    bio.seek(0)
#    print(bio.read())                  FIRST print
    bio.seek(0)
    my_base64_jpgData = base64.b64encode(bio.read())


    result["image"] = my_base64_jpgData
```

And at the end of my code what i do is:

```
    result = handler(input)
    file = open("image.png", "wb")
#   print(base64.b64decode(result["image"]))         SECOND print
    file.write(base64.b64decode(result["image"]))
    file.close()
```

The problem I have is that both the first and the second print print the same thing, but clearly if I write it to a file the file is all white because there is some junk information, in fact this is what the two prints return:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02\x80\x00\x00\x01\xe0\x08\x06\x00\x00\x005\xd1\xdc\xe4\x00\x00\x009tEXtSoftware\x00Matplotlib version3.3.1, https://matplotlib.org/\xdd\xdd\xfc\xf3\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0fa\x00\x00\x0fa\x01\xa8?\xa7i\x00\x00\x08\xc9IDATx\x9c\xed\xd61\x01\x00 \x0c\xc00\xc0\xbf\xe7\xe1\x02\x8e&\nzv\xcf\xcc,\x00\x002\xce\xef\x00\x00\x00\xde2\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b\x0c \x00@\x8c\x01\x04\x00\x881\x80\x00\x001\x06\x10\x00 \xc6\x00\x02\x00\xc4\x18@\x00\x80\x18\x03\x08\x00\x10c\x00\x01\x00b.&y\x07\xbc\xa7\xa7\xb2b\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```

As you can see, almost immediately appears `0\x00\x009tEXtSoftware\x00Matplotlib version3.3.1, https://matplotlib.org/\xdd\xdd\` and i think for this the image `image.png` that my code produces is a white image.

Do you know how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I find by myself how to solve the problem (but i don't understand why it works), I hope it will help someone in the future.

The problem is "simply" the line `plt.show()`, deleting this line it will work correctly.